# How Can I make a Input box with validation like the one on Azure portal?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I noticed this very nice input box with js validation (on azure.com portal), and want to find out, how can I get a similar one for my web projects.

I noticed that some fx-..... css are being aplied, so maybe it's some standard Lib or framework ?

```
<input id="manage-coadmin-email" class="fx-textbox fx-validation fx-editablecontrol fx-editablecontrol-edited fx-validation-required-valid fx-validation-length-valid fx-validation-regex-valid fx-validation-isValidCoAdminEmailAddress-valid fx-validation-valid fx-validation-deferred-valid" type="text" data-link="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" data-val="true" data-val-required="You must enter a value in the field." data-val-regex="The email address can contain only letters, numbers, periods, hyphens, and underscores. The address can contain only one at sign (@)." data-val-regex-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$" data-val-length="Specify a value that is not longer than {0} characters." data-val-length-max="254" data-val-isvalidcoadminemailaddress="The co-administrator must sign in with a user account from an associated directory."></input>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution in the meantime ? We are looking into the same area and do not really find a library or so ...

Answer (score 0):

I've done something very similar, using [MVC Remote Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) to handle the AJAX validation and the input groups in [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) to handle the compound input/icon.

Comment: Any sample ? The goal is to have that Green or Red icon display inside of the input, and show a nice progress 'circle' while validation is being executed

Comment: And Yes, Remote Validate attribute - rocks :)

Comment: It depends in that case then, it might be better to use jQuery.  You can wire up the onchange event of the input box to trigger an AJAX call to handle the validation.  You could then swap the `img` tag's `src` attribute for the loading image.  Then the action method on your controller doing the validation can return a `JsonResult`.  Then in your AJAX call on the client, you can handle success or failure by again swapping out the `src` attribute for either a success or failure image.